# resize columns in compact framework 2.0 datagrid

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I'm working on windows mobile 6.0 project using compact frame work 2.0
I'm looking to resize the data grid column to fit the screen (i  have only 3 columns).
Any help please?

Comment: Can your share your code and a screenshot of what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to look for the datagrid TableStyles/DataGridTableStyle and ColumnStyles.

See MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229684%28v=vs.80%29.aspx for an example.

The Width property of the ColumnStlye allows you to set the width to fit your needs.